# Python Tkinter Function Order Problems

Tags: python, tkinter

I've been having a problem with a program which searches two files for a specific string (in this case, the numberplate of a vehicle). The base program on a command line interface works fine, however, I cannot seem to be able to get the GUI version functional. I suspect it's because the GUI interacts with the standard functions differently, but I am not sure how to solve this problem.

```
import csv, sys, tkinter.messagebox
from tkinter import *

mGui = Tk()

def read(Numberplate):
    if len(Numberplate) != 7:
        return False
    with open("Test Data.csv","r") as data:
        for row in data:
            if Numberplate in row:
                global details
                details = (row)
                return True
            else:
                return False
    data.close()

def read2(Numberplate):
    with open("Data.csv","r") as data2:
        for row in data2:
            if Numberplate in row:
                global speed
                speed = str("The vehicle\'s speed was " + row[8:] + "mph.")
                return True
    data2.close()

def callback():
    Numberplate = grab.get()
    if read(Numberplate) == False:
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Results","This numberplate has not been recorded.")
        quit()
    if read(Numberplate) == True and read2(Numberplate) == True:
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Results",(speed + details))

grab = StringVar()

mGui.configure(bg="blue")
mGui.title("Database Searcher")

mlabel = Label(text="Please enter the numberplate in the box below:",bg="purple").grid(row=0,column=3,columnspan=2)

mbutton = Button(mGui,text="Search",command=callback,bg="green").grid(row=5,column=3,columnspan=2)

mbox = Entry(mGui,textvariable=grab).grid(row=3,column=3,columnspan=3)

mGui.mainloop()
```

The idea of this program is to search two files to see if there is a mutual numberplate between them. If so, their speed and driver's details are meant to be extracted and printed into a message box. At the moment, all entries seem to return the same error message, even if the entry is correct.

Thank you for reading and I would appreciate any help given.

Comment: Could you please show also your `csv` file?

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that if the length of `Numberplate` is different from 7, your `read` function will always return `False`?

Comment: Please, add your file to your question, which makes things easier to read...

Comment: Yes, that is the desired function. The numberplates stored in the csv files are all standard, so the all follow the usual scheme of LLNNLLL (with L denoting a letter, and N denoting a number). If the length is not 7, the numberplate will not be in the csv and so False should be returned.

Comment: Also, why do you need this statement `global details` in your read function?

Comment: The idea is that "details" can be referenced in the callback() function.

By the way, how do I directly upload the csv files?

Comment: You can simply `edit` (by clicking the **edit** under your post) your question and add the contents of your file....

Comment: Forget what I said before, it's correct what you are trying to do, even if I usually use `global` for a slightly different purpose, but you can also do what you are trying to do..

Comment: haha, please forgive me, I am a tkinter and StackOverflow newbie. Adding  just the contents of the files makes them quite difficult to read, is there a way I could upload the entire file?

Also, how do I make details a global variable outside the function?

Comment: See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47689/how-can-i-attach-a-file-to-a-stack-overflow-post) possibilities on how to upload a file..

Comment: https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=A4143C903F48087B%21108

https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=A4143C903F48087B%21107

Comment: I will try to see what is the error, and I will come back with my attempt's result ;)

Comment: Could you post please the error you are receiving? Also, are you aware of the fact that one of the files you link to has the following name `Data.csv.txt`, instead of `Data.csv`, like you are trying to open it in your `read2` function?

Comment: It seems like I have fixed the issue myself. Regardless, thank you for all your help and I hope my program wasn't too hard for you to navigate :-P. I'd be absolutely happy to rep you if you post an answer or something.

Comment: You can also answer your own question, so that future visitors with similar problems can understand what is going on.